# Why does generating a random number outside of a loop, causes it to be always the same?

Tags: javascript, random, while-loop

When I create a random number inside a while loop as a local variable everything works, but when I generate a random number as a global variable then I get stuck in an infinite loop.
I don't understand how and why this should make any difference.
Goal is to output all the random numbers that are less than 0.7 with a While Loop.

Here is the code that creates an infinite loop:

```
let rnd = Math.random();
let continue = true;

while (continue) {
  console.log(rnd);
  if (rnd > 0.7) {
    continue = false;
    alert(rnd + ' is bigger than 0.7!');
  }
}
```

Here is the code that works (only thing that is changed is that the random number is generated within the while loop).

```
let continue = true;

while (continue) {
  let rnd = Math.random();
  console.log(rnd);
  if (rnd > 0.7) {
    continue = false;
    alert(rnd + ' is bigger than 0.7!');
  }
}
```

I'm not interested in creating this with another kind of loop, I'm just trying to understand the While Loop better.

Comment: The first code only calls `Math.random()` *once*, when `rnd` is declared. The value is never updated in the loop.

Comment: It has nothing to do with scope (local vs. global), it's just that you only assign a single value to `rnd` when it's a global, but you assign a different value to `rnd` each time when it's a local. You could do that assignment with a global as well (leave off the `= Math.random()` part where you declare it, then do `rnd = Math.random()` in the loop), but since you don't need `rnd` anywhere outside the loop body, it's appropriate to declare it within the loop body. In general, keep variables narrowly-scoped.

Comment: It seems so obvious now :'( Thank you everyone for good answers.

Comment: Side note: `continue` is a reserved keyword.

Answer (score 1):

```
let rnd = Math.random(); 
let continue = true;


while (continue) {
console.log(rnd);
    if (rnd > 0.7) {
        continue = false;
        alert(rnd + ' is bigger than 0.7!');
    }
}
```

- Here, the random number generator will only execute one time, before the while loop. If th random number isn´t > 0.7, continue would be always true and it will be an infinite loop.
- However, if the random number is generated locally in the while loop, in each loop a new number will be generated so you only need to wait for a rnd number > 0.7.

Answer (score 1):

It is because when you declare `Math.random()` as a variable it creates a binding with a random value which doesn't change. Example: 0.8.

And if it is less than or equal to 0.7 then it would result in an *infinite loop* because the value doesn't change with each iteration.

In the second example it works fine because it is declared locally and it's value changes with each iteration.

Hope you understood.